# Is there a term for a "dual-language" book?

Tags: vocabulario

I have found dual language books very helpful in studying foreign languages, including Spanish. I've often wondered if the genre is also commonly found in the Spanish-language publishing world.

Does this generic term, "dual-language book" exist in Spanish? If so what is it?

Comment: is it simply a matter of adding "Bilingüe"?

Comment: It is.  Bilingüe is the word you are asking for.

Comment: Please make these the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term is, actually, `Bilingüe`.

Answer (score 2):

Simple y sencillamente "bilingüe".